# Is it possible to connecting Cloud Dataflow into Compute Engine in different region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, google-vpc

We have kafka deployed on the compute engine at asia-southeast1 region, and we need to do streaming processing on the apache beam (cloud data flow). based on my research, the only way to connecting it is via vpc network. but, unfortunately data flow is not available yet on asia-southeast, and if we deploy the dataflow on the other region we cannot connecting it via vpc network.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#specifying_a_network_and_a_subnetwork

is there any other solution to connecting compute-engine with dataflow on the different region?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Dataflow is available across all regions in Pacific Asia. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#asia-pacific) for further information.